# Creating Debian file using jdeb plugin

Tags: plugins, debian, maven-plugin

How we creating debian file using jdeb plugin ? There are multiple way to create the debian file .After  lot of stuff we reaches on solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing R&D on creating Debian file using jdeb plugin.
Create the directory deb/control/ in your src/ directory of your project.Inside this you need to create control.txt file with following content:-

```
Package: <Package Name>
Version: <Version>
Section: misc
Priority: optional
Architecture: all
Depends: 
Maintainer: Darshan <bobra.darshan@gmail.com>
Distribution: development
Homepage: http://www.yourwebsite.com/
Description: insert up to 60 chars description insert long description, indented with spaces
```

After these all you need to add plugin on POM file i.e

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.vafer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jdeb</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>deb</id>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jdeb</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <verbose>true</verbose>
                                <deb>target/${project.build.finalName}${project.version}.deb</deb>
                                <controlDir>/home/dbobra/workspace/projectName/src/deb/control</controlDir>
                                <dataSet>
                                    <data>
                                        <src>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</src>
                                         <type>directory</type>
                                        <mapper>
                                            <type>perm</type>
                                            <prefix>/home/dbobra/installed/tomcat/webapps/${project.build.finalName}</prefix>
                                        </mapper>
                                    </data>
                                </dataSet>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Hope this works on your problem.

Comment: It would be good to know why the Q/A was down-voted so furiously. Was it the poor English or factual flaws or low Q/A standard? The author ought to know.